# How to create expandable view on top of mapview

Tags: android, android-layout

Could anyone tell me how to create an expandable view like this on top of mapview. Like in google maps.
[image]

Comment: One easy way to do this would be to create a custom `DialogFragment` and show it when every you need.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create the layout you want to display on top in xml.

Using FrameLayout as the parent, first add the map and then add your view that you want to display on the top.